# Upgraded to Spring 4.3.0 and static JS files are now served as 'application/octet-stream' instead of 'application/javascript' as in Spring 4.2.6

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc

I recently upgraded from Spring 4.2.6 to 4.3.0 and now I'm receiving the following error in Chrome when my web page tries to load **static javascript files**.

> Refused to execute script from `http://.../someJsFile.js` because its MIME type ('application/octet-stream') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

I double-checked the response header (using Spring 4.3.0) and I indeed see `Content-Type:application/octet-stream`. However, when I drop back down to Spring 4.2.6 I see `Content-Type:application/javascript`.

The files are included in my page like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- ... -->
<body>
  <!-- ... -->
  <!-- Adding type="text/javascript" does not help -->
  <script src="/resources/js/someJsFile.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my *applicationContext.xml* has the following config

```xml
<!-- ... -->
<context:component-scan base-package="some.package.spec" /> 
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<!-- ... -->
```

I tried looking at the Spring 4.3.0 release notes, but nothing immediately stood out.

Any ideas what changes in 4.3.0 are affecting me? How do I tell Spring 4.3.0 to set the correct content type for static javascript files? Let me know if you need more details about configuration, etc.

Comment: Same problem for me, +1

Comment: Same problem, different content type for me. Javascript files are served properly but SVG files are served with the content type 'application/octet-stream'. +1

Comment: Created a [bug report](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14368).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was added to milestone 4.3.1 (see [bug report](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14368)) and marked as completely resolved on version 4.3.3.

Js modules (mjs) are still served as application/octet-stream by springframework web. In order for them to be served as application/javascript, it is necessary to map the mime type in servlet descriptor (web.xml):

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>mjs</extension>
    <mime-type>application/javascript</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Comment: Am still seeing a similar problem on 4.3.2 with SVG files in the resources directory.

Comment: @Tor the problem went away for me in 4.3.1. You should either comment on the existing bug report or file a new one.